# How to iterate in web scraper? I want to loop through all the matching elements and print them

Tags: python, web-scraping

This [URL](https://www.bmw.com/en/automotive-life/bmw-3-series-generations.html) has details about 7 generations of the BMW series. How can I iterate through each of these generations and get the output?

Here's the initial code, based on `requests` and `ElementTree`

```
page = requests.get('https://www.bmw.com/en/automotive-life/bmw-3-series-generations.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

generations = tree.xpath(
    '/html/body/main/article/div[1]/div/div[13]/div/text()'
)

generations = tree.xpath(
    '/html/body/main/article/div[1]/div/div[13]/div/text()'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to it, I would highly recommend using beautifulsoup for scraping like this. It greatly simplifies the process and results in more readable code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://www.bmw.com/en/automotive-life/bmw-3-series-generations.html')

# parse the page
page = BeautifulSoup(resp.content)

# relevant class attributes found by just looking at the site html 
# in a browser, you may need to alter it slightly to get the desired divs 

# find_all works very similarly to querySelectorAll
for x in page.find_all(attrs={'class': 'col col--s4 has-nested-row'}):
    # get text will pull all inner text from child elements of selected 'x' elem
    print(x.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

The page has a total of 14 sections in generation's details, 2 for each generation (1st for features, and 2nd for description). Here's the to fetch the details.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import requests

def main():
    url = 'https://www.bmw.com/en/automotive-life/bmw-3-series-generations.html'
    for elem in BeautifulSoup(requests.Session().get(url).text, 'lxml').find_all('div', {'class': 'pw-m-listicle'})[::2]:
        pprint({
            'Generation': elem.find('div', {'class': 'pw-m-listicle__headline'}).text,
            **{list_elem.text.split(':')[0].strip() : list_elem.text.split(':')[-1].strip() for list_elem in elem.find_all('li')},
            'Description': "\n".join([p.text for p in elem.find('p')])
        })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
{'Built': '1975-1983',
 'Description': 'It’s the year 1975: “Jaws” was selling out movie theaters and '
                'breaking box office records worldwide. Youngsters wore flares '
                'and platform shoes, and the mini-skirt was still the height '
                'of fashion.',
 'Generation': '1st generation',
 'Power': '55-105 kW / 75-143 hp',
 'Variants': 'Sedan (2-door), Convertible (Baur Topcabriolet)'}
{'Built': '1982-1994',
 'Description': '1982: Answering machines, microwaves, and VCRs became '
                'standard appliances in every household. The first video games '
                'reached the mainstream, with Pac-Man leading the way, while '
                'rock songs like “Eye of the Tiger” topped the charts.',
 'Generation': '2nd generation',
 'Power': '66-175 kW / 90-238 hp',
 'Variants': 'Sedan (2 and 4-door), Convertible, Baur Topcabriolet, Touring, '
             'M3 (as Coupé and Convertible)'}
{'Built': '1990-2000',
 'Description': 'Wide-leg jeans and flannel shirts were all the rage. Boy '
                'bands were in their heyday, thanks to the success of groups '
                'like the Backstreet Boys and New Kids on the Block. Families '
                'could suddenly use a modem to go “online.” Welcome to the '
                'nineties!',
 'Generation': '3rd generation',
 'Power': '73-236 kW / 99-321 hp',
 'Variants': 'Sedan, Coupé, Convertible, Baur Topcabriolet, Touring, Compact, '
             'M3 (as Sedan, Coupé, and Convertible)'}
{'Built': '1997-2006',
 'Description': 'It was in 1997 that the blockbuster movie “Titanic” broke '
                'cinema records. Suddenly, piercings and tattoos had become '
                'commonplace, while text messaging became an everyday mode of '
                'communication. The comet Hale-Bopp shifted the world’s focus '
                'up into the night sky.',
 'Generation': '4th generation',
 'Power': '77-265 kW / 105-360 hp',
 'Variants': 'Sedan, Coupé, Convertible, Touring, Compact, M3 (as Coupé and '
             'Convertible)'}
{'Built': '2005-2013',
 'Description': '“Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire” was the '
                'highest-grossing movie of 2005. The charts were dominated by '
                '50 Cent, Mariah Carey, and Gwen Stefani. YouTube’s story of '
                'success begins.',
 'Generation': '5th generation',
 'Power': '90-331 kW / 122-450 hp',
 'Variants': 'Sedan, Coupé, Convertible, Touring, M3 (as Sedan, Coupé, and '
             'Convertible)'}
{'Built': '2011 onwards',
 'Description': '“Game of Thrones” began its march of triumph on screens '
                'around the world, singer Adele won six Grammy Awards and '
                'director Michel Hazanavicius created a beautiful homage to '
                'the silent movie era with his film “The Artist”.',
 'Generation': '6th generation',
 'Power': '85-338 kW / 116-460 hp',
 'Variants': 'Sedan, Touring, Gran Turismo, M3'}
{'Built': '2018 onwards',
 'Description': 'Google’s AI Asisstant can now make real phone calls and '
                'schedule appointments, “Avengers: Infinity War” comes to the '
                'big screen, and construction of the Jeddah Tower – soon to be '
                'the world’s tallest building – is well underway.\xa0',
 'Generation': '7th generation'}
```